# How can I get stdn.readline() to read in inputs

Tags: python-3.x, io, stdout, stdin

**Objective:** to read a number of test cases and two separate integers per line.

For example:

```
*INPUTS*
1

1 1

*OUTPUT*

2

*INPUTS*

2

3 9

*OUTPUT*

12
```

```
from sys import stdin, stdout 
T = int(input())
for i in range(T):
    A, B = [int(i) for i in stdin.readline().split()]
    stdout.write(str(A + B)+"\n")
```

The above code creates a ValueError:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-cfdb0a961cfe> in <module>
      2 T = int(input())
      3 for i in range(T):
----> 4     A, B = [int(i) for i in stdin.readline().split()]
      5     print(A, B)

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have blank lines in your input. Either remove them or skip them in your code.